# Do I need a special kind of linear regression for aggregated data?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, aggregation, geostatistics

I have two separate databases on individuals. But these individuals are not both present in the two databases. So I decided to aggregate them into area-level data (such as State-level). One of the databases now has an aggregated sentiment score for each State (calculated by averaging from the individual sentiment scores within each State, for example: Alaska(0.33) and Florida(0.23)). For the other database, I have an aggregated percentage of education in each State (calculated by first dichotomizing individual into 1(have some college education) and 0(have no college education at all), and finding the percentage of people with at least some college education, for example: Alaska(65%) and Florida(75%)).

I would like to see if there is a statistically significant relationship between State-level sentiment and State-level education percentage, can I simply use simple univariate linear regression, or do I need some kind of adjustment for the within-State variability?

Comment: Another issue is that some states are bigger than others

Comment: I did try to eliminate your concern by excluding states that have less than 100 individuals in either of the two databases.